# Can't run exe file with argumnets

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I want to run an exe file using `child_process` of node js here is the function I have :

```js
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
const { execFileSync } = require('child_process');

let base64String = req.body.image;
let base64File = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();
let dir = '/server/html/upload';
let file = dir+'/image.png';

fs.writeFileSync(file, base64File, {encoding: 'base64'});

let exeprog = path.normalize(__dirname + '/upload/program.exe');
let imagefile = path.normalize(__dirname + '/upload/image.png');
let destfile = path.normalize(__dirname + req.body.file);

let child = execFileSync(exeprog , [imagefile, req.body.field, destfile , 'TRUE']);
res.json(child)
```

When I run this code I got this error :

```
Error: spawnSync C:\server\html\upload\prog.exe
EINVAL
```

I'm missing something in my code, knowing that the **nodeJS** version I'm using is : `8.15.0` and the application is started with **administrative rights**

Comment: Had you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067734/how-to-pipe-and-save-output-of-spawnsync-process-in-node-js

Comment: Have you verified that the path causing the error is actually an executable file?